# after successfully running the query in PGADMIN not able to see the result

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I m new to PGADMIN
when i run a query ,message pop up saying successfullu run
but i am not able to see the result of the query

Like in mysql workbench
when i run

```
select from customer
where customer_name='abc'
```

it shows the all the name of customers name of **abc**
but in **PGADMIN** i am not able to see the result

and is there anyway to create the database and table in pgadmin other than clicking and selecting create database and table

Comment: You have selected no columns.  Postgres allows this syntax, but the results are not interesting.  Presumably you want `select *`.

Comment: thank you it was just a typo,

Answer (score 1):

yes, you have not selected the columns in the query.

```
select * from customer
where customer_name='abc';
```

Comment: thank you i was just a typo, can you also please tel me how to add a column in postgres before and after a column

Comment: Please follow [link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-add-column/) 
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-add-column/
thank you.

Comment: FYI: 
 `ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN new_column_name data_type constraint;`

add column in the table only add columns in the end. you cannot add columns before and after columns. you may need to recreate the table again.

Comment: @sasmzna ,so adding table at specific position is only available in mysql and in microsoft sql ??

Comment: @JayantRajput: no, it's not possible (and it's not possible in SQL Server either). And it's not needed the order of the columns in a relational table is meaningless. If you need a specific _output_ order, just write the columns in the SELECT list in the order you want. Using `select *` isn't really recommended to begin with.